# Serialization of TestRunType throwing an exception

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, xml-serialization, trx

I'm trying to analyse some trx files (webTestResults) to output synthetic excel files.

first, I take the trx xsd schema (vstst.xsd in visual studio directory) to generate a bunch of C# Classes.

then, I try to instantiate an XmlSerializer based on the type of TestRunType (generated from the schema).

```
XmlSerializer xmlSer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(TestRunType));
```

The XMLSerializer instantiation raises an exception :

```
System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting type 'TestRunType'. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting property 'Items'. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting type 'TestRunTypeTestDefinitions'. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting property 'Items'. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting type 'OrderedTestType'. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting type 'CodedWebTestElementType'. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting property 'Items'. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: Member 'CodedWebTestElementType.Items' hides inherited member 'BaseTestType.Items', but has different custom attributes.
   at System.Xml.Serialization.StructMapping.FindDeclaringMapping(MemberMapping member, StructMapping& declaringMapping, String parent)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.InitializeStructMembers(StructMapping mapping, StructModel model, Boolean openModel, String typeName, RecursionLimiter limiter)
```

what are the custom attributes ? 
Just the beginning of BaseTestType :

```
public abstract partial class BaseTestType {

    private object[] itemsField;

    private bool enabledField;

    private string idField;

    private string nameField;

    private bool isGroupableField;

    private int priorityField;

    private string namedCategoryField;

    private string storageField;

    public BaseTestType() {
        this.enabledField = true;
        this.isGroupableField = true;
        this.priorityField = 2147483647;
        this.namedCategoryField = "";
    }

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Agent", typeof(BaseTestTypeAgent))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Css", typeof(BaseTestTypeCss))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("DeploymentItems", typeof(BaseTestTypeDeploymentItems))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Description", typeof(object))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Execution", typeof(BaseTestTypeExecution))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Owners", typeof(BaseTestTypeOwners))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Properties", typeof(BaseTestTypeProperties))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("TcmInformation", typeof(TcmInformationType))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("TestCategory", typeof(BaseTestTypeTestCategory))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("WorkItemIDs", typeof(WorkItemIDsType))]
    public object[] Items {
        get {
            return this.itemsField;
        }
        set {
            this.itemsField = value;
        }
    }
```

And CodedWebTestElementType :

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010")]
public partial class CodedWebTestElementType : BaseTestType {

    private object[] itemsField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("IncludedWebTests", typeof(CodedWebTestElementTypeIncludedWebTests))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("WebTestClass", typeof(CodedWebTestElementTypeWebTestClass))]
    public object[] Items {
        get {
            return this.itemsField;
        }
        set {
            this.itemsField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Could someone explain to me what the problem is ?

thanks...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The solution is to remove Items property from the derived classes (`CodedWebTestElementType` and `GenericTestType`), BUT also to move the serialization attributes to the base class in order not to miss the values in case you have a coded web test or a generic test.

IOW, the solution is the following.

First, remove `Items` property from `CodedWebTestElementType` type

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.1")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(Namespace="http://microsoft.com/schemas/VisualStudio/TeamTest/2010")]
public partial class CodedWebTestElementType : BaseTestType {
}
```

Then, move it's two `XmlElementAttribute` attributes to the `BaseTestType` base class (see the last two):

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Agent", typeof(BaseTestTypeAgent))]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Css", typeof(BaseTestTypeCss))]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("DeploymentItems", typeof(BaseTestTypeDeploymentItems))]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Description", typeof(object))]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Execution", typeof(BaseTestTypeExecution))]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Owners", typeof(BaseTestTypeOwners))]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Properties", typeof(BaseTestTypeProperties))]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("TcmInformation", typeof(TcmInformationType))]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("TestCategory", typeof(BaseTestTypeTestCategory))]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("WorkItemIDs", typeof(WorkItemIDsType))]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("IncludedWebTests", typeof(CodedWebTestElementTypeIncludedWebTests))]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("WebTestClass", typeof(CodedWebTestElementTypeWebTestClass))]
public object[] Items
{
    get {
        return this.itemsField;
    }
    set {
        this.itemsField = value;
    }
}
```

After that, do the same thing for the `GenericTestType` class.

This way you will not lose the information in case you get **IncludedWebTests**, **WebTestClass**, **Command** or **SummaryXmlFile** nodes one day.